# Creating combinations and maintaining combination count in a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` which looks like this:

```
memberid    created    firstencodedid    questionid
123       <some date>    <some ID>          4fc
123       <some date>    <some ID>          daf
123       <some date>    <some ID>          f82
123       <some date>    <some ID>          cfd
123       <some date>    <some ID>          730
```

There are over 350,000 `memberid` values and over 100,000 `questionid` values, and the length of the `DataFrame` is over 45 Million records.

For each `memberid` value, I'd like to generate all possible combinations of `questionid` and maintain the count of each 'pair'.

By 'pair' I mean each `questionid` paired with each other `questionid`, for a particular `memberid`.

For example, here are all the 'pairs' for the `memberid` `123` in the dataset displayed:

```
['4fc','daf']
['4fc','f82']
['4fc','cfd']
['4fc','730']
['daf','f82']
['daf','cfd']
['daf','730']
['f82','cfd']
['f82','730']
['cfd','730']
```

So as a first step, I tried to generate all the question pairs. The RAM (16GB) obviously wouldn't be able to hold such data in, so I thought of writing this data (the 'question pairs') to a file using the following code:

```
import itertools
import csv
start_time = time.time()
def generate_combination_of_questions(dataframe):
    return [
        pair
        for _, questions in dataframe.groupby('memberid')
        for pair in itertools.combinations(questions.questionid, 2)
    ]

with open('file_name', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for memberid in IncorrectQuestions['memberid'].unique():
        for pair in generate_combination_of_questions(IncorrectQuestions[IncorrectQuestions['memberid']==memberid]):             
            writer.writerow(pair)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This code works, but it generated a 210GB file and then I ran out of disk space. The counts for every 'pair' would obviously be calculated after the file would be written successfully, which didn't happen.

I tried another method of trying to create `OrderedCounter` using the following code:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

from collections import Counter
q1AndQ2Occurrences = OrderedCounter()
for memberid in IncorrectQuestions['memberid'].unique():  
  subset_IncorrectQuestions = IncorrectQuestions[IncorrectQuestions['memberid'] == memberid]
  q1AndQ2Occurrences = q1AndQ2Occurrences + OrderedCounter(generate_combination_of_questions(subset_IncorrectQuestions))
```

This method turns out to be very slow, and I'm also quite sure that my memory will give up at some point.

Given this large dataset, what could be the best way to create these 'question pairs' and maintain a count of each 'question pair'?

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA.

**EDIT**

I don't want to keep the entire dataset in memory, but I'd like to know the count of each combination for each `memberid` value. Some combination might repeat across `memberid` values, I'd like to add such counts.

@Boud's solution tells me the number of combinations for each `memberid`, but doesn't tell me which combination has what count.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create a giangantic amount of data to count them instead of applying the combination math function ?????

```
import scipy as sp

N = df.groupby('memberid').questionid.count()
N.apply(lambda x : sp.misc.comb(x, 2))
Out[10]: 
          questionid
memberid            
123             10.0
```

Comment: Or just generate the counts and/or pairs on demand - struggling to think of a reason anyone would want to keep the entire lot in memory at once...

Comment: @Boud: Thanks for your answer. But this code would not tell me what the `question pairs` are. This is giving me the number of combinations for each `memberid`. I'd like to know the count for each combination. There will also be some combinations that will appear across various `memberid` values. I'd like to add those counts, too. It's possible that I may be going about it the wrong way, in which case, I'd appreciate a twist in my arm and shown the right way.

Comment: @JonClements okay, seeing the latest comment we are in the XY problem zone. I'll just let my answer as I think it's always valuable to remind combinatorics results should be computed from math and not from data in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Boud on the necessity to store a list in memory. But if you have to do it, consider a dataframe like this:

```
d = {'memberid': [123,123,123,456,456], 'questionid': ['4fc', 'daf', 'f82', 'cfd', '730']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


    memberid    questionid
0   123         4fc
1   123         daf
2   123         f82
3   456         cfd
4   456         730
```

You can

```
df.groupby('memberid').apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x['questionid'], 2)))
```

It will give you

```
memberid
123    [(4fc, daf), (4fc, f82), (daf, f82)]
456                            [(cfd, 730)]
```

EDIT:

You can get the count of combinations for each memberid like this:

```
df.groupby('memberid').apply(lambda x: len(list(combinations(x['questionid'], 2))))
```

It will return

```
memberid
123        3
456        1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I've added more clarification in the question.

Comment: This could work. I doubt the memory will be able to hold the output of this entire command, coz I expect hundreds of Millions of `question pairs`. But I can write a generator on top of it and store these individual `memberid` results in a flat file. Then I can just `group by` on these pairs and add the counts for samme pairs across `memberid` values. I will accept your answer once I have it implemented. Thanks a lot for you help, much appreciated.

Comment: So I ran the following code: `IncorrectQuestions[IncorrectQuestions['memberid'] == 123].groupby('memberid').apply(lambda x: len(list(itertools.combinations(x['questionid'], 2))))` and it gave me the following result: `memberid
123    561
dtype: int64`. So unfortunately, it's still not giving me the combinations and counts that I was expecting.

Comment: What I am expecting is as follows: 

memberid    pair    count
123       [4fc,daf]   1
123       [4fc,f82]   1
123       [daf,f82]   1
456       [4fc,f82]   1
456       [daf,f82]   1

Comment: I am surprised that the count using len is not working, its working here and giving the output I printed in my answer

Comment: given that we are talking about unique combinations, won't the pair count like 123 [4fc,daf] 1 always be 1?

Comment: No they wouldn't. This is just a sample dataset I have posted. In the actual dataset, the combinations would be repeated.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have used `combinations`, and I'm assuming you referred to `itertools.combinations`. Is that correct? Coz I can't seem to understand why the same piece of code would work for you and not for me.

Comment: Yes, thats itertools.combinations